# SQLCommand in C# Not Supplying Parameter

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a function in c# that is to insert data. All it is supposed to do is call a stored procedure given from a Request Body that I supply through Fiddler. Right now I'm trying to test it but I keep getting this error.

"Procedure or function 'spCreatePerson' expects parameter '@first', which was not supplied."

Here is the object-

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int PersonTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the request body -

```
{"FirstName":"Test","LastName":"MuhFuh","Phone":"5555555555","Email":"test@gmail.com","PersonTypeId":1}
```

Here is the function for calling the proc-

```
public static int InsertData(string procName, Person p)
    {
        int rowsAffected = 0;

        con = CreateConnection();

        using (con)
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("spCreatePerson", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", p.FirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last", p.LastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", p.Email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", p.Phone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pTypeID", p.PersonTypeId);

            rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        return rowsAffected;
    }
```

As you can see I passed in the parameter but am getting this error. Is there something I missed in the code? I stepped through it and the data seems to be passed just fine.

**EDIT**

Here is the stored procedure-

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[spCreatePerson] @first nvarchar(100), @last 
nvarchar(100), @email nvarchar(50), @phone nvarchar(100), @pTypeID int

AS

INSERT INTO Person(FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, PersonTypeID)
VALUES(@first, @last, @email, @phone, @pTypeID)


GO
```

Comment: When debugging, does `p.FirstName` contain a value?

Comment: @David Yeah. "Test" is being passed in from the request body just fine. I debugged it all the data seems to be going through.

Comment: Can you add stored proc script to the question here?

Comment: One strange thing is that you are setting cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; before creating the SqlCommand. After that you are recreating this object and this is potential problem. Never use global SqlCommand. Better write it var cmd = new SqlCommadn("stuff", con); cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: @Sujith Yeah just added it in.

Comment: @mybirthname wow! switching it around worked. And alright I'll change that in my code now. Thanks man!

Comment: @KrazyDev stop using global variables it is bad practise. This will help you in the future to avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *might* be the culprit, but at the very least this is a variable in the whole equation to eliminate.  These lines are very suspect:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd = new SqlCommand("spCreatePerson", con);
```

For one thing, the second line is completely negating the first.  They should be swapped:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("spCreatePerson", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

But more to the point, they illustrate a much bigger potential problem.  Namely...

> Where are `cmd` and `con` even declared and created?

If you're using connection and command objects which exist in a larger scope, you're potentially sharing them with other operations.  This is a bad thing, and can lead to very difficult to diagnose bugs.

**As a general rule of thumb, one should declare, create, use, and dispose of commands and connections in as small a scope as possible.**

You're not gaining anything by keeping them around, the underlying system is *pretty well* optimized.  But what you are doing is opening up the possibility of bugs and strange behavior in the code.

The structure should basically be (in somewhat-pseudo-code):

```
using (var con = new Connection())
using (var cmd = new Command(con))
    // set parameters, command type, etc.
    // execute the command, get any results you might need
}
// any follow-up logic, etc.
```

Comment: They were global variables in my DBHelper class.

Comment: @KrazyDev: An ironically named class :)  Seeing that this method is also `static` is another potential problem.  You might want to take a look at something like the repository pattern (which is trivial to implement with Entity Framework).  Or at least service classes which act like repositories.  Basically, stick with object-oriented code.  "Global" things and "make everything static" is a slippery slope to a dark world of buggy code.